# Downloading video from URL using python results in file with 0 byte

Tags: python, web-scraping, get

I'm currently trying to do some web scraping from this website: https://likee.video/hashtag/CuteHeadChallenge?lang=en

I managed to extract video link by using selenium, beautifulsoup and json here are the following code:

```
  #click the element
  element.click()
  time.sleep(3)
  page = wd.page_source
  souptest = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

  # code to get vid from clicked element here
  data = json.loads(souptest.find('script', {"id" : 'videoObject', "type" : 'application/ld+json'}).text , strict=False)

  folderpath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/LikeeData/' + data["author"]["name"]
  video = data["contentUrl"]
```

Problem is when I tried to download the url, the downloaded file will have the size of 0 byte, here is what I tried:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(video, folderpath + '/vid.mp4')
```

```
req_file = requests.get(video)

with open(folderpath + '/vid.mp4', "wb") as file:
  file.write(req_file .content)
```

Then I noticed that the the get request returned response 204 so I tried some solutions from another thread

```
r = requests.get(data["contentUrl"], stream=True)
  while r.status_code == 204:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('still 204')
    r = requests.get(data["contentUrl"])
```

but it did not work and always return 204, when I open the link in my browser it returns response 200, when I change the url to the thumbnail it worked, it did not work only when I tried to download video url, here is one such video url: https://video.like.video/asia_live/2s2/2Dz9d6_4.mp4?crc=1506960817&type=5

Please help me find out what is wrong here, thank you for you assistance

Comment: normal browser may send some cookies and headers which server may use to check if you can get this video. But `urlretrieve` doesn't use it - and this can make problem

Comment: I have no problem to download with `requests`. But it uses different header `User-Agent` than `urllib`. Or maybe it will block me when I will try to download many, many files.

Comment: @furas thank you very much for your insight, I tried to create requests in a different colab notebook and it worked I'm not quite sure why I think I'm just going to have a separate script for getting the links and downloading the video.

Comment: `requests` sends `User-Agent: Python/3.8, Requests/2.x` and `urllib` sends different value - and server may use this value to block scripts/bots - but rather it should block both because they send value different then real browser - like `Mozilla/5.0 ...`

Comment: I'm back, I tried but I found out that I can only get successful request if i change notebook and colab account, same thing with **Andrej Keselys** code, I furas is right in that I have been blocked

Comment: it shows that scraping is not easy. Now it would need some proxy servers to download every file from different IP. And this need to find proxy servers - and free proxy servers often doesn't work becuse they are outdated and servers already know them and block them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this example how to download all videos on the page (without a `selenium`):

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://likee.video/hashtag/CuteHeadChallenge?lang=en"
api_url = "https://api.like-video.com/likee-activity-flow-micro/videoApi/getEventVideo"

payload = {
    "country": "US",
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 28,
    "topicId": "",
}

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"window\.data = ({.*});", html_doc)[1]
data = json.loads(data)

payload["topicId"] = data["topicId"]


data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

# print/save each videoUrl:
for i, video in enumerate(data["data"]["videoList"], 1):
    print("Downloading {} as {}.mp4".format(video["videoUrl"], i))
    # download video
    with open("{}.mp4".format(i), "wb") as f_out:
        f_out.write(requests.get(video["videoUrl"]).content)
```

Prints:

```
Downloading https://video.like.video/asia_live/2s2/2Dz9d6_4.mp4?crc=1506960817&type=5 as 1.mp4
Downloading https://video.like.video/asia_live/2s1/2gaWZB_4.mp4?crc=1571964795&type=5 as 2.mp4
Downloading https://video.like.video/asia_live/2s1/2RLMdC_4.mp4?crc=779823808&type=5 as 3.mp4

...
```

and saves the videos.

Comment: Update it worked well for awhile but my internet disconnected in the middle, when I tried to rerun it it returns 204